# GnuPG on Wampserver

Tags: php, wampserver, gnupg

Can you please tell me how do I install and use GnuPG on wampserver ? I seriously want that.

I hope this question comes under stackoverflow. If not please close this but please dont downvote me :(

Comment: You might get better answers on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get GnuPG as a PECL package here: http://pecl.php.net/package/gnupg

It looks like you'll need to compile it yourself though. It comes with a config.m4 file, so you'll probably want to use autotools (cygwin?).

Instructions on how to install it are here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

It sounds like you just have to put the .dll you compile in the correct directory.

You'll also need to install GnuPGME: http://www.gnupg.org/gpgme.html

One of the commenters on php.net wasn't able to get it to install, so it might not work anyway..

Comment: thanks for the knowledge. so is there any way to decrypt and encrypt gpg on windows. any GUI app ? (apart from gpg4win-2.0.3)

Comment: @atif089 what are you trying to encrypt? Email, random files?

Comment: random files, or to be precise i want to store/retrieve that info from  a database

Comment: @atif089: My suggestion is maybe look at the OpenSSL stuff: http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php It sounds easier to install on Windows. It has some public key encryption stuff.

Comment: thanks. I can use this from now but the problem is I already have some data encrypted