# Fatal error: Call to undefined function gnupg_init()

Tags: php, windows

Does anyone know why this `error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function gnupg_init()` displays when I run the following code below?

```
<?php
$res = gnupg_init();
?>
```

Comment: What server are you using? And what operating system?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using wamp server 5.2.6

Comment: `gnupg` extension is not `installed`. [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103845/gnupg-on-wampserver) for details

Answer (score 0):

GNUPG extension [is not available](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/) on windows, so you would need to either build it yourself or use unix server/vm